# PyQt QFileDialog exec_ is slow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

I'm using a custom `QFileDialog` because I want to select multiple directories.
But the `exec_` function is very slow, and I can't figure out why. I'm using the newest version of PyQt.

Code Snippet:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtNetwork, uic

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)            
        self.connect(self.multiPackerAddDirsBtn,
                     QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.multiPackerAddDirs)

    def multiPackerAddDirs(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
        dialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.Directory)
        dialog.setOption(QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, True)
        dialogTreeView = dialog.findChild(QtGui.QTreeView)
        dialogTreeView.setSelectionMode(
            QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        if dialog.exec_():
            for dirname in dialog.selectedFiles():
                self.multiPackerDirList.addItem(str(dirname))
                print(str(dirname))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What platform are you on? Is the file-dialog *always* slow, or only when you use the code you've posted?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. If I use a predefined method like getSaveFileName its fast but if I create a custom dialog with dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self) and use dialog.exec_() it's slow as hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QFileDialog` constructor creates a Qt dialog, whereas the static functions (like `getSaveFileName`) will create a native one (unless the [DontUseNativeDialog](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) option is set to `True`).

The native dialogs may be faster or slower than Qt's, depending on the platform in use.

For some plaforms, though, it appears the problem may be more acute. See [this longstanding bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13182), which affects Windows XP and Windows 7 (amongst others) with Qt 4.7 / 4.8.

**UPDATE**

Just to be clear:

On Windows, the static function [QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) opens the native "Browse For Folder" dialog, which only allows selecting a single directory. So Qt cannot provide a *native* dialog for selecting multiple directories, because Windows doesn't provide one.

The other main alternative is to use Qt's own, non-native file-dialog and monkey-patch it as suggested in [this faq](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/when_the_filemode_is_directoryonly_in_my_qfiledialog_how_can_i_select_multi). However, as you've already discovered, this currently has the significant downside of being annoyingly slow due to bugs in the underlying implementation.

The only remaining alternatives are to either write your own directory-lister dialog, or try to think of another way of solving your immediate problem (i.e. without using a file-dialog).

Comment: I tried to make DontUseNativeDialog False but it didn't had an effect.
Is there another way to create a file dialog where I can select multiple directories?

Comment: @Ahsous. There's not much more to be said on this, but I've updated my answer as best I can.

Answer (score 1):

I had very very slow performance from the default Qt file browser dialog. Listing a directory took ~5s and selecting a file took ~3s. Adding the "DontUseNativeDialog" option fixed my problem completely.

```
file_path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName( self, 'Title', path, "", "", QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog )
print file_path
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! For QT6.5.2, it's QFileDialog.Option.DontUseNativeDialog