# PyQt QFileDialog- get the path of multiple directories

Tags: python, pyqt, qfiledialog

However I found an older discussion about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544425/pyqt-qfiledialog-multiple-directory-selection), it is not clear for me how to get the paths of the selected folders...

The combined codes from the source mentioned above is the following...

```
class FileDialog(QtGui.QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QFileDialog.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setOption(self.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        self.setFileMode(self.DirectoryOnly)

        for view in self.findChildren((QtGui.QListView, QtGui.QTreeView)):
            if isinstance(view.model(), QtGui.QFileSystemModel):
                view.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FileDialog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which is able to select the folder, bit I do not know how to store them in a container.

The selection of files it is easy...like

```
fileNames = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,'Open Images','',selectedFilter='*.dcm')
```

I would like to use something like this, can you help me?...sorry for the thumb question.

Comment: `ex.exec_(); print(ex.selectedFiles())`.

Comment: It works, now the program stops when I choose the directories and prints their paths in a list form. Just anothe thing...could you please comment why is there a "u" before the directory path in the list? I mean when I print it I got this:  [u 'c:/....', u'c:/....']

Comment: The `u` indicates they are unicode strings rather than byte strings (in Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how y'all got it working. This is the code I tried, with the imports included. However, after outputting the selected folders, it hangs, which means something is wrong.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class FileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QFileDialog.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setOption(self.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        self.setFileMode(self.DirectoryOnly)

        for view in self.findChildren((QtWidgets.QListView, QtWidgets.QTreeView)):
            if isinstance(view.model(), QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel):
                view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FileDialog()
    ex.show()
    ex.exec_()
    print(ex.selectedFiles())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There's an updated example provided by ekhumuro on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28548773/453673).